# Play HTML5 video located on network server

Tags: html, video

I want to play a video with html5 video tag from a network server.

I'm also make the test with an image, but I got, with Google Chrome, the error "Not allowed to load local resource".

I've already searched and this happens by security reasons of the new web browses.

For the video I'm using the basic html. If I play the video from my computer, like, it work well (obviously)

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="videos/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

But when I change the source to: 'file:///fileof1/FILESRV/videos/movie.mp4', nothing happens.

Anyone with a solution?

Comment: Set up a server that can “stream” the file contents via HTTP on your “network server.”

Comment: I can't install anything in the "network server"...

Is there a way to get the video with php?